# Regarding Max flow problem ( Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm)

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

I'm looking for the max flow in this graph but something is going wrong.

[image]

First I take the path : 1-2-4-6. So the flow ie $F=1$

Then : 1-3-2-5-4-6 and the flow updates to $F=2+1=3$

If i take the path : 1-3-5-6 my flow is $F=3+2=5$

And the graph is disconnected now. I can't  reach 6 starting in 1. I know the maximum flow should be 6 but I think the algorithm stops when there's not path joining the source and the target.

What's the extra condition I'm missing? How can i find the maximum flow?

Comment: "If i take the path : 1-3-5-6 my flow is $F=3+2=5$": Shouldn't it be $F=3+3=6$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

So you just proved (by counterexample) that *maximum* flow is not the same as *maximal* flow.

To construct the maximum flow, look at the graph and note that minimum cut of size $6$ occurs in $\{(2,4),(2,5),(3,5)\}$, so all of these have to be used to maximum capacity, and in your flow they are not.

If you need more hints, ask questions...

Comment: Yeah I was looking for a minimum cut when i realized there was a problem. That's the reason i thought the maximum flow should be 6. In theory Ford-Fulkerson's algorithm should end with the maximum flow so.. what was my mistake?  I can give more information if needed.

Comment: @Abellan you need another iteration I think, or the other ones come in the wrong order...

Answer (score 1):

There are two flows,
1) forward flow (directed edge)
2) reverse flow (opposite to edge direction)

```
0 <= forward flow - reverse flow <= capacity of edge
```

so in residual network, there will be reverse capacity available for every forward flow

```
available reverse capacity = forward flow - reverse flow
```

In above case, there is reverse capacity of 2 available from node (2) to node (3), so there is one more path possible 1->2->3->5->6 F = 5 + 1 = 6.